# How to install node-red-dashboard to Node-RED on IBM Watson IoT?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, watson-iot

I started Watson IoT Platform Starter on IBM Cloud, Node-RED deployed a boilertemplate.
Now I remodeled the template node, and got following fluctuating numerical data per inject.

```
node: cpu status
msg.payload: string[4]
"18.5"
```

I'd like to draw line graph from these datas.
I couldn't find visualization nodes from node list, so I tried to install "node-red-dashboard" but install failed occurred.Where do you think my procedure has problems?

Event log:

```
2019-09-07T13:52:03.430Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --save --save-prefix="~" --production node-red-dashboard@2.16.2
2019-09-07T13:52:23.311Z rc=null
```

Comment: Could be due to any number of reasons. Do you get an error message from your npm install of the dashboard?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately event log is this only. As a test, I installed Node-RED at my local CentOS7 server, then node-red-dashboard installation was successful. This may be an Watson IoT specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely that the `npm` process is being killed for using too much memory.

You can try increasing the memory assigned to your application or enabling continuous integration and editing the `package.json` file to include the dashboard as a dependency and then restaging the app. This would cause the dashboard to installed as part of the app setup where it should be allowed to complete.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. IBM Watson IoT is fully integrated as cloud service. That is so powerful but has minimum resources. I will install Node-RED at my local server again.